# Dynamic(Moving) Gestures using OpenCV

Tags: opencv, gesture-recognition, motion-detection, opticalflow

I can detect hands or colored marker using openCV but I'm stuck at recognizing dynamic gestures(eg. Moving hand to right as move right gesture). I want to recognize left, right, up, down, circle (clockwise and anticlockwise)
Can you please suggest me a way of achieving above described gestures.

Comment: I'm looking for similar thing doing through Python OpenCV. Have you achieved dynamic moving gestures successfully? Can you help me to getting started?

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at the [motempl.c](https://code.ros.org/svn/opencv/trunk/opencv/samples/c/motempl.c) sample from OpenCV. It allows you to track motion history gradients.

The primary functions you will be interested in are:

- [updateMotionHistory](http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/video/doc/motion_analysis_and_object_tracking.html#updatemotionhistory)
- [calcMotionGradient](http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/video/doc/motion_analysis_and_object_tracking.html#calcmotiongradient)
- [calcGlobalOrientation](http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/video/doc/motion_analysis_and_object_tracking.html#calcglobalorientation)
- [segmentMotion](http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/video/doc/motion_analysis_and_object_tracking.html#segmentmotion)*

> * You may not want to segment things by motion since you have an
>   object segmentation algorithm already...

To only track the object in which you are interested, simply preprocess the video with your object detection algorithms, and then apply motion history tracking to the detected object.

Hope that helps!